# Load flash file fom inside flash, but with parameters?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Question: I need to load a swf file from inside my flash.
Now, normally I would use loadClip, but I need to pass a parameter (filename) to this swf.
How can I pass a parameter there?

Comment: Can you pass the parameter using GET? e.g. when loading the child SWF, do loader.load(new URLRequest("child.swf?filename=settings.xml"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the best solution but have you tried loading the swf file with an absolute path?

```
var container:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("container", this.getNextHighestDepth());
var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
loader.loadClip("http://mydomain.com/flash/test.swf?param1=1", container);
```

You can also establish a communication between both swf based on events as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763575/can-i-pass-parameters-from-and-external-swf-using-actionscript-3-0).